# Why would you perform a Bit-shift twice ((x >> 4) << 4)?

Tags: c++, emulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

So I am analyzing a Nes-Emulator code and I've come across this line of code that I can't make any sense of:

```
nMapperID = ((header.mapper2 >> 4) << 4) | (header.mapper1 >> 4);
```

Why is header.mapper2 bit-shifted once to the right and then to the left.

The header by the way is this struct:

```
struct sHeader
{
    char name[4];
    uint8_t prg_rom_chunks;
    uint8_t chr_rom_chunks;
    uint8_t mapper1;
    uint8_t mapper2;
    uint8_t prg_ram_size;
    uint8_t tv_system1;
    uint8_t tv_system2;
    char unused[5];
} header;
```

Comment: Lets say you have `11110011`, what does `(11110011 >> 4) << 4` give you?

Comment: Not 100% but would it be 11110000?

Comment: Correct.  Now do you get why they did it?

Comment: @HamzaKhan correct.  Shifting to the right N times, and then shifting to the left N times, effectively sets the rightmost N bits to 0. In this case, `(header.mapper2 >> 4) << 4` is effectively the same as `header.mapper2 & 0xF0`

Comment: What's the point of `char unused[5];`?

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I do, the mapper-Id would therefore be the top 4 bits of mapper2 (as the top 4 bits of mapper-ID)  and the top 4 bits of mapper (as the bottom 4 bits of mapper-ID).

Comment: @Asadefa, since this is an emulation, its basically matching the header structure used in the iNes file. Some of the bits are redundant but still emulated.

Comment: @HamzaKhan OK then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit-shift is *not* a rotation of bits. The new bits that appear are all 0s. So this expression:

```
(header.mapper2 >> 4) << 4)
```

first *clears* the 4 lower order bits, and then shifts all the bits back to the left.

e.g. if you had a bit pattern like `01010101`, the right-shift would first make the bits `00000101`, and then the left-shift would make it `01010000` (hence clearing the rightmost 4 bits).

If it *were* a rotation of bits (as you seem to expect), then it would indeed be effectively a no-op.

Comment: It's also of interest that it does it irregardless of the size of `header.mapper2`. Do to so with a mask, one would need to match the mask size to the integer size, while this way is pretty much size agnostic.

Comment: @AdrianMole to mask off the bottom 4 bits, you would need to use `0xF0` instead of `0x0F`. And you would need to use `&` instead of `&=`, as the code is not modifying `mapper2`, only reading it

Comment: @AdrianMole It's not better, I'd say it's actually a lot worse since the performance of bitshifts on modern Intel processors is terrible: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rp6_bfZ4nuE

Comment: It's _also_ a lot worse because it's a dependency chain of two operations where one operation (which would otherwise run in parallel to shift on the right hand side of the | operator on virtually every processor)  would do, too. I'm not sure the compiler is allowed to just optimize it as a bitwise AND anyway. Hopefully that's in a cold code section, so it won't matter whether you spend 2 cycles or 15 cylces, anyway.